# How to query grand children from a list of persons?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, iqueryable

Below in this code, I have explained what I want , Please someone help me to solve this problem.

```
public class Person
{
    public IEnumerable<Child> Children { get; set; } 
}

public class Child
{
    public IEnumerable<GrandChild> GrandChildren { get; set; } 
} 

public class SearchingClass
{
    public void Search()
    {
        IEnumerable<Person> persons = MyPersons;
        IEnumerable<GrandChild> grandChildren = MyGrandChildren

        //Now I want only the Grand Children who are grand children of persons in Persons List 
        //How can I write a query for this ? 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What's the table schema? An ORM solution will have awful performance. Better to create a view or stored procedure that will perform a hierarchical query and map the results

Comment: Impossible to create a view , I am using SQL CE Compact as datasource

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
perons.SelectMany(p => p.Children)
      .SelectMany(c => c.GrandChildren); 
      // add Distinct() if you need distinct results
```

If you need to get only those grand children which are in `grandChildren` collection:

```
grandChildren.Intersect(
    perons.SelectMany(p => p.Children)
          .SelectMany(c => c.GrandChildren));
```

Comment: Performance will be attrocious though, as you have to load P*C*G entries, although it's unavoidable as long as you try to do such queries with an ORM

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos agree, it's better to use `IQueryable` query to filter items on server side

Comment: I would say, better to use a CTE to make a hierarchical query/view/stored procedure (preferably with a HierarchyID field), then map the results

Comment: Can I know what does this "Intersect" method do ?

Comment: @user3030035 sure: [Enumerable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos first query is not that bad with ORM - simple inner join query